# UTF-8 SELECT IBM i DB2 throught unixODBC php PDO Debian 9 in CLI php

Tags: php, mysql, db2, ibm-midrange, unixodbc

I have a problem, very very picky.

I have a LAMP server which is connected to an IBM i (AS400) throught unixODBC. PHP execute sql on IBM i throught ODBC connection on IBM i.

I want to do a simple SELECT in my databse.
It's work very well when the script is executed by a navigator (apache), but when the script is executed by CLI (php example.php) and when i have special characters like : Ô ô é à @ etc in my record PDO return NULL. And when i execute the script in my Web browser all the special characters are okay.

I don't understand why. I put 'CHARSET=UTF-8' in my DSN PDO connection.

I think this bug is related to : [iSeries Access ODBC Driver with unixodbc on Debian - Invalid UTF-8 characters being returned from iSeries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364027/iseries-access-odbc-driver-with-unixodbc-on-debian-invalid-utf-8-characters-be?rq=1) because when I SELECT with HEX(field) i have the hexa from browser and CLI.

PHP latest version (7.4.6), Debian 9.

Comment: Question has not enough facts.  Is the hostname that runs Apache (where the script returns the correct data)  the same hostname as the one that runs your script via CLI ?    Give details.  Next, when you run the script via CLI, in your terminal window on Debian9, what is the *shell* and specifically what is the value of LANG variable in that shell session?

Comment: I resolve this problem. It was because my shell language param was not set to utf8 and my language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment thread, the cause of the issue was that when running from the command-line shell and php CLI, the shell was not correctly configured for UTF-8 for the correct locale (country etc).